# display image for instanced select-box

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I've created a mat-form-field within an formArray, which allows me to display an image inside the option tag of the select box.[image: Like this, Multiple select boxex]

Now I want to display to the left side of the filled inputfields the an image of the actor.  Meaning the following:
This is the component ts to update/edit a show information and it's episodes. I'm already showing a small preview of the image of the actor in the option field.
What I'm trying to accomplish is once the actor is selected, to show a bigger image on the side of the input fields Actor/Char Name.
Since a Show can have multiple actors "imgBig" is overwritten with the last selected actor for the Show.
I somehow need to create duplicatable variable which I can access in the templates FormGroup. That way I can say imgBig+i (i being the FormGroup index number) and it should show me the correct image

the html looks like this

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
<mat-select  formControlName="cast" class="form-control">
<mat-option  *ngFor="let c of actorList;let i=index;" value="{{c.imdbId}}" class="form-control" style="height:60px;" >
{{c.combinedname}} || {{c.imdbId}}
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>  
<img src="{{imgBig}}" style="border-radius: 100%;"/>
```

The data I'm gettig from a json looks like this

[image: Array_Data]

I tried this within my typescript

```
export class EditShowComponent implements OnInit {

  imgBig :any;
  showForm: any
  showList:any = {}
  selectedShow_ = '';
  actorInfo:any;
  info:any;
  actorList:any = {};
  prevSelA :any = 0;
  prevSelEP :any = 0;
  epNr :any;
  epiIndex:number=0;

...
  setTitleValues(r:any){
    //console.log('valuesset start');
    console.log(r);
    //console.log('valuesset end');
    this.showForm.get('name_en').setValue(r[0].name_en);
    this.showForm.get('name_kr').setValue(r[0].name_kr);
    this.showForm.get('imdbId').setValue(this.selectedShow_);
    this.showForm.get('asianwiki').setValue(r[0].asianwiki);
    this.showForm.get('releasedate').setValue(r[0].releasedate);
    this.showForm.get('baseImg').setValue(r[0].baseImg);
    this.imgBig = r[0].imgBase;
    this.epiIndex = -1;
    if(this.prevSelA==0)
    {
      
      //console.log('if');
      
      this.prevSelA = this.sd.setActorCount(r[0][0].length);
      this.casts.removeAt(0);

    }
    else{
      //console.log ('else');
      this.prevSelA = this.sd.getActorCount();
      while (this.casts.length !== 0) {
        this.casts.removeAt(0);
      }

    if(this.prevSelEP==0)
    {
     
      this.prevSelEP= this.sd.setEpisodeCount(r[0].episodenZahl); 
      //this.casts.removeAt(0);
    }
    else{
      this.prevSelEP = this.sd.getEpisodeCount();
    }

    this.epNr = r[0].episodenZahl;
    while (this.episoden().length !== 0) {
      this.episoden().removeAt(0)
    }

    if(r[0][1])
    {
      for(let tt of r[0][1]){
        //console.log('E:::'+tt.episode);
        this.addEpisode();
        var tIndex = tt.episode;
        tIndex = tIndex-1;
        
        this.createEpisodenDescDBdata(tIndex,tt)
        //this.descs(tt.episode).push(this.newEpisodeDecription());
      }
    }


    
    console.log('cast daten begin');
    console.log(r[0]);
    console.log('cast daten ende');
    //console.log(r[0]);
    
    for( let tt of r[0][0])
    {
      this.casts.push(this.buildExistingActor(tt.imdbCid,tt.alias,tt.imgBig));
    }
    //this.casts.removeAt(0);

  }  
...
  buildExistingActor(n:any, a:any,bild:any):UntypedFormGroup {
    this.imgBig = bild;
    console.log("actor name "+n);
    console.log("actor alias "+a);
    return this.fb.group({
      cast:[n],
      alias:[a],
      bigImg:[bild]
    })
  }
}
```

The image get's displayed next to the field but it's always the same image because it basically always overwrites the older img saved in the variable "imgBig"
Any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: Instead of ... you have to provide the full snippet of your `component.ts` code. Looking at your code, there's no way to tell how you are setting different value for `imgBig`. Also `<img src="{{imgBig}}" style="border-radius: 100%;"/>` is not running a loop, so it is coded to show the most recent value of `imgBig`

Comment: I've add now the correct component.ts script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create another variable as an array and fill the array with the imgBig value within the buildExistingActor method

```
export class EditShowComponent implements OnInit {
imgBigB: any =[];
...
setTitleValues(r:any){
    let k = 0;
    for( let tt of r[0][0])
    {
      this.casts.push(this.buildExistingActor(tt.imdbCid,tt.alias,tt.imgBig,k));
      k++;
    }
    //this.casts.removeAt(0);

  }
... 


  buildExistingActor(n:any, a:any,bild:any,pos:any):UntypedFormGroup {
    this.imgBigB[pos]=bild;
    console.log('bigB START');
    console.log(this.imgBigB);
    console.log('bigB END')
    this.imgBig = bild;
    console.log("actor name "+n);
    console.log("actor alias "+a);
    return this.fb.group({
      cast:[n],
      alias:[a],
      bigImg:[bild]
    })
  }
```

this allowed me to access the correct Image in the template while using the formGroup index as the array index for the assigned image

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
  <mat-select  formControlName="cast" class="form-control">
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let c of actorList;let i=index;" value="{{c.imdbId}}" class="form-control" style="height:60px;" >
        <img src="{{c.imgSmall}}" style="border-radius: 100%;"/>{{c.combinedname}} || {{c.imdbId}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>     
<img src="{{imgBigB[i]}}" style="border-radius: 100%;" height="150px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, but I am guessing you want to show an image of each actor in mat options list.

The issue is you are always setting a single value for `imgBig`, as seen in the line `this.imgBig = bild;`.

What if you use `imgBig` or `imgSmall` fields from the `actorList` array. You can update the `<mat-option>` line to do following:

```
<mat-option  
 *ngFor="let c of actorList;let i=index;" value="{{c.imdbId}}" class="form-control" style="height:60px;" >
 <img [src]="c.imgBig"> <span>{{c.combinedname}} || {{c.imdbId}}</span>
</mat-option>
```